# Flink SQL: Emitting an event after a certain time has passed after original event was recorded

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql, event-stream-processing

I am trying to setup a data streaming pipeline that starts with a task to emit an event after a certain time (say 5 days) has passed after a certain other event has been registered in Kafka topic.

Basically, the use case is a chain of marketing communications, that needs to happen in a certain order, after client has opened an account. If client has not performed a certain task in a period of 5 days, I need to emit an event to create a communication reminding him or her to perform an activity. Then a next one after 10 days for another task.

I am wondering if such chain of triggers can be setup using Flink SQL.

Thanks!

I am not a developer, just doing preliminary feasibility analytics, before going deeper into architecture and specification. Searched for similar questions on SO and online, but it seems there's nothing specific to Flink SQL.

Comment: This use case isn't a good fit for Flink SQL.

Comment: Thank you, David. Following your Flink 101 videos on youtube :)